# Debugging C++ static lib from C#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

This question is similar to this unanswered question: [Debugger does not step into native code when debugging a static lib wrapped in a C++/CLI DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661185/debugger-does-not-step-into-native-code-when-debugging-a-static-lib-wrapped-in-a)

The setup is the same. I have a pure C++ static library that is linked to a C++/CLI DLL which is then used by a C# executable. Depending on the settings, I can either debug the C# layer, or both C# and C++/CLI. No matter what I try, I can't debug the C++ layer. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Here's what I have tried and the results. For all scenarios described below, I have breakpoints set on the C++/CLI and C++ functions (not the C#).

1. C# with native debugging, C++ and C++/CLI with auto debugging: The debugger stops at the calls in C# that would invoke the C++/CLI functions, but I cannot setp into them. Visual Studio has no messages for the breakpoints on the C++/CLI side (they are active but can't be hit). On the C++ side, it says:

```
This breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoints in module clr.dll are not alowed. This module contains the implementation of the underlying runtime you are trying to debug.
```

2. C# without native debugging, C++ and C++/CLI with mixed debugging: breakpoints in C++/CLI are hit and active. C++ breakpoints either disappear, or have the following message:

```
This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.
```

3. C# with native debugging, C++ and C++/CLI with mixed debugging: see the first point, the behaviour is identical.
4. C# without native debugging, C++ with native debugging, and C++/CLI with mixed debugging: same as point 2.

The code I have is the following:

C++ Native.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
namespace native
{
   class Native
   {
   public:
      Native();

      bool here() const;
   };
}
```

C++ Native.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Native.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace native
{
   Native::Native()
   {
      std::cout << "Created native entity!" << std::endl; // breakpoint here
   }

   bool Native::here() const
   {
      std::cout << "Native is here!" << std::endl; // breakpoint here
      return true;
   }
}
```

C++/CLI Wrapper.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../cpp/Native.hpp"

using namespace System;

namespace clr
{
    public ref class Wrapper
    {
   public:
      Wrapper() 
      { 
         Console::WriteLine("Building wrapper for native"); // breakpoint here
         mNative = new native::Native(); 
      }
      ~Wrapper() { delete mNative; }
      bool go() 
      { 
         Console::WriteLine("In wrapper to find native..."); // breakpoint here
         return mNative->here(); 
      }

   private:
      native::Native* mNative;

    };
}
```

And C#:

```cs
using System;
using clr;

namespace csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
            Console.WriteLine("Finding native through wrapper...");
            w.go();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of and I cannot debug the C++ side. I would really appreciate any help figuring this out.

Comment: You're wasting a lot of time testing scenarios that have no hope of working because they tell the debugger to not look at native C++ code.  Use your configuration #3 and add the intrinsic function call `__debugbreak();` inside your native C++ code. This WILL make the debugger stop there. You will probably get complaints from the debugger that symbols are not loaded, or the source code path is not configured correctly, or something like that. Once you resolve the particular things that prevent source-code debug when you hit `__debugbreak()`, setting breakpoints in source will start working too.

Comment: Also, what is your "Just debug my code" option set to in the Visual Studio debugger options?

Comment: Finally, the question you linked to may be "unanswered" but the programmer there got his debug experience working by enabling "Compatibility" mode in his Visual Studio debugger options.

Comment: That first error message is quite wonky, hard to guess what could cause that one.  Do make sure you link the debug build of that library.  Don't try to step into the native code, that can never work, only a breakpoint is able to switch the active debugging engine.  You absolutely must use the old debugging engine (the good one), Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" must be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be as simple as `Enable native code debugging` not being enabled in Visual Studio.

learn.microsoft.com's [Tutorial: Debug C# and C++ in the same debugging session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019) contains the steps for a successful c#+c++ debugging session.

Comment: In my various attempts I have enabled native code debugging in the C# side. In fact, numbers 1 and 3 have it enabled (I guess I could have explained that better), and I still can't get the debugger in the C++ side. I have looked at the tutorial that you mention and I can get it to work with a simple C++ DLL and a C# executable. My issue is having the C++ static lib wrapped in a C++/CLI dll and then calling that from C#.

Comment: @Mauricio: It is not even worth trying with "Enable native debugging" disabled (your cases 2 and 4) because that is the setting that is supposed to control this feature.  Focus on your case 3, which is supposed to work.

Comment: This answer contains the correct setting to debug. I basically reset eveyrthing to default settings, toggled `Enable native code debugging` and it worked. Not sure what exactly was going on. Leaving the debuggers in auto works.